# Prefix field when serializing with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'd like to prefix a field with a string value whenever the object gets serialized. Is there a way to do this with Jackson? I'd like to prefix the class name to the id.

```
public class CarClass {
  public Long id;
  public String name;
  ......
}
```

And example class would be...

```
CarClass car1 = new CarClass (1,"First car");
```

And I want it to be searilized like so:

```
{ 
  "id": "carClass-1",
  "name": "First car"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try JsonGetter annotation:

```
public class CarClass {
  public Long id;
  public String name;
  
  @JsonGetter("id")
  public String getPrefixedId() {
    return "carClass-" + id;
  }
}
```

[Jackson annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)